# dvi-ps-pdf-chain not working, while non-dvi chain works

Tags: texstudio, eps, dvi

I am using TeX Studio 2.5.2. When I choose the Build & View to be `txs:///compile | txs:///view`, my document, which contains **.eps** images and with `epstopdf` package used, is generated nicely.

However, this generates a pdf file for each image used, and I have a lot of them, so I thought maybe if I use a different chain it should work. So I tried `txs:///dvi-ps-pdf-chain` based on a colleague's advice, but it gives me an error: `file_name.dvi: No such file or directory This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) dvips.exe: DVI file can't be opened:`
Any ideas?

Comment: that means a dvi file was not made so presumably you had an error in the latex run, what does the `.log` file say?

Comment: Process started: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode "ile_name".tex

Process exited with error(s)


Process started: dvips.exe -o "ile_name".ps "ile_name".dvi

ile_name.dvi: No such file or directory This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) dvips.exe: DVI file can't be opened:

Process exited with error(s)

Process started: ps2pdf.exe "file_name".ps

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Process exited normally

Comment: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.2.4)  1 JUN 2015 13:39
entering extended mode
filename.tex". The file name is some specific name, shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: But what does the log file say: what tex error did you get:-)

Comment: The log file is too long and I couldn't identify the exact error, see: http://pastebin.com/eVavj8mt

Answer (score 3):

You are running dvips to convert a DVI file but you used `pdflatex` rather than `latex` so no DVI file was generated, the log starts

```
  This is pdfTeX, 
          ^^^^^^
```

and ends

```
Output written on "NNONGO Noise PRL v8.pdf" (5 pages, 655293 bytes).
                                     ^^^^^^
```

(Note having spaces in file names is a major source of problems, I'd avoid that)

Comment: I removed the spaces and replaced the default compiler from `txs:///pdflatex` to `txs:///latex`, but still got the same error.

Comment: @student1 what does the log say!!!! you can not possibly get the same log file if you do not use pdflatex.

Comment: I checked the log, there are some citation related 'warnings', some 'info', and paths related to 'dvips', command definitions, package info, but no clear error.  http://pastebin.com/WE8ZqgZT

Comment: @student1 please don't use links to external sites, but that paste does not show the end of the log it just stops at line 1361 so impossible to say why no dvi file is generated or found.